# Only display Published items in <li>

Tags: component, php, joomla-3.3.x

I have written a component that outputs a list in ul format.  Currently the UL is built with the following:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : ?>
        <?php if ($item->latest_issue == '0') echo 
            "<li role='presentation'><a role='menuitem' tabindex='-1' href='" . $item->reader_url . "' target='_blank'>" . $item->issue_date . "</a></li>" ;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

The only problem with this is that if an item is Unpublished, it still shows in this list. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: i think you should filter only published items in model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simply check to ensure the `state` isn't `0`, like so:

```
$item->state != 0
```

So your code would be:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : ?>
        <?php if ($item->latest_issue == '0' && $item->state != 0) echo 
            "<li role='presentation'><a role='menuitem' tabindex='-1' href='" . $item->reader_url . "' target='_blank'>" . $item->issue_date . "</a></li>" ;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Here is my version of your code which is prettified a little more. Always be sure to use `: >> endif` or `{ >> }` for you conditional statements. I know you don't have to but when it comes down to debugging, it makes life so much easier:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : ?>
        <?php if ($item->latest_issue == '0' && $item->state != 0) : ?>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="<?php echo $item->reader_url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $item->issue_date; ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

---

#### Update:

The ordering will be done in your model/database query like so:

```
->order($db->quoteName('id') . ' ASC');
```